# sbt stage is taking forever

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala.js

I support Play! web application written in Scala. 
For development purposes I use `sbt run` and it works fine. 
I understand `sbt stage` command is a good option for preparing to deploy your app. 
However, in my case this command takes very long (3-5 minutes, and then I break out of it). 
The project is far from gigantic, it has 370 Scala source files and uses Scala.js. 
I use sbt 0.13.5 with Scala 2.11.6. 
May be I misunderstood something?

UPDATE - I tried running `sbt -mem 2048 stage` - it finished in 208 seconds. I guess, this is a win. Also it seems some build step is making it slow

**UPD** - this is really embarassing: I read [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) and thought that `stage` command they're talking about is `sbt stage`. Turns out it was `activator stage`. Sorry everyone

Comment: How much memory are you giving to sbt?  The most common problem is not enough RAM for the process...

Comment: @JustinduCoeur you mean to the JVM that runs sbt itself? via SBT_OPTS?

Comment: Is that `stage` from `sbt-native-packager` ?

Comment: @rumoku I believe so, yes